# Discord.NET - Framework version issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, discord.net

I am trying to write a bot for the Discord chat program in Visual C#. However, when I try to install Discord.NET from the NuGet package manager, it says I need .NET framework version 4.5, which is the one I have. I tried restarting my computer but it still doesn't work.

Thanks,
Matt

I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate.

Comment: when you say that you have .NET 4.5, do you mean that you have it installed on the machine? or do you mean that you set in project properties that 4.5 should be used for this project?

Comment: Installed on machine, I think that might have been the error. Ive replaced vs 2010 with vs 2012 now, and ill set that properties thing so it should be alright

Comment: Is your project created with .NET 4.5 framework?

Comment: I never heard of [DISCORD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software)) but it seems like $20M was put into the development. VOIP and instant text-messaging for gamers.

Answer (score 2):

In your Visual Studio, you can right-click on the project, select properties, and in the opened dialog you will be able to set target version of .NET framework